# correlated subquery with exists and top clause using cte

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, exists, correlated-subquery

```
with x as 
( select max(sal),deptno from emp
  group by deptno
)

select * from emp
where exists

(select top 1 1 x on x.max_sal=e.sal and x.deptno=e.deptno)
```

It's going to fetch records of max sal in each department

1. I don't have any idea why we are using top 1 1 and what does it mean?
2. What is the use of exists operator?

Comment: Provide your table definitions and some sample data set related to your question

Comment: Are you sure this is [mysql]? `TOP`is MS Sql Server lingo.